# Non capturing named groups in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I wrote the following regexp to match all the outer most blocks in a set of nested blocks using `scan` method.

```
input.scan(/[^{}]++\{((?:[^{}]+|\{\g<1>\})++)\}/)
```

or

```
input.scan(/[^{}]++\{(?<paren>(?:[^{}]+|\{\g<paren>\})++)\}/)
```

The problem with this code is that the parentheses I used for `?<paren>` group are causing the `scan` to capture only the content of `?<paren>` group while I need to capture the entire string matched by `scan` method. What do i need to do about this problem?

Comment: Put the whole pattern in a capture group (and change `\g<1>` to `\g<2>`)

Comment: I will post an other way with only one capturing group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When capture groups are present, the scan method will only return the content of these capture groups but will no more return the whole match.

A solution consists to put the entire pattern in a capture group to solve the problem. However, each results will be a couple of string with the content of the capture groups 1 and 2.

To avoid the problem you can rewrite the pattern with only one capture group like this:

```
((?<={)(?:[^{}]+|{\g<1>})*+|[^{}\s][^{}]*{\g<1>})
```

[online demo](http://rubular.com/r/BLgFl5Ifvt)

edit: or without capture groups at all:

```
(?<={)(?:[^{}]+|{\g<0>})*+|[^{}\s][^{}]*{\g<0>}
```

**Notes:**
The lookbehind at the begining is here to check if you are in a recursion or not.

`[^{}\s][^{}]*` is used instead of `[^{}]+` to avoid leading spaces and newlines.

Comment: It took me time to understand your masterpiece.

Comment: @Sajjad: If you don't understand something, do not hesitate to ask me in a comment.

Comment: When I saw the title of this question I thought, "I'll bet Casimir's had something to say about that", and sure enough, you did. Good answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: thanks for your encouragements (they give me the opportunity to correct my pattern), and nice to see you!